# Super Foreign Key or Composite Key

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

```
ALTER TABLE `SWIMMER`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk5` FOREIGN KEY (`CoachID`, `Country`) REFERENCES `TEAMMEMBER` (`MemberID`, `Country`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`MemberID`, `Country`) REFERENCES `TEAMMEMBER` (`MemberID`, `Country`);
```

I'm using this SQL query and unfortunately it runs but the designer mode in phpmyadmin isn't showing up the relation between the TeamMember table and the Swimmer table which is a supertype and subtype relation in this database. Please Let me know if you can do this kind of sql query or you need to make some other connection.

```
ALTER TABLE `SWIMMER`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk5` FOREIGN KEY (`CoachID`, `Country`) REFERENCES `TEAMMEMBER` (`MemberID`, `Country`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`MemberID`, `Country`) REFERENCES `TEAMMEMBER` (`MemberID`, `Country`);
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: So from this model - is MemberID not globally unique, but only unique per country. Is that correct? I would usually use a surrogate key this key which is globally unique, and might make the rest of this question simpler.

Comment: So, the thing is in phpmyadmin the designer mode isn't showing that there's a relation between Swimmer table and TeamMember table as I've made both attribute as a super key/ composite key in the main table and as it's a super and subtype relation and swimmer in exclusive subtype entity of TEAMMEMBER, I don't know how can I use MemberID, Country as primary key in TEAMMEMBER table and PRIMARY and FOREIGN key in SWIMMER table to build this relation.

Comment: @TomC Thank you very much! Actually your explanation gave me a great idea to fix my design in order to maintain the efficiency and achieving the right goal.